# In Django. How to sort using field length

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-orm

How to sort using field length
results like this:

```
Model.objects.all().order_by(len("field"))
```

sql:

```
 select * from table order by len(field)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Django 1.8 and above, you can do:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length

obj = Model.objects.all().order_by(Length('field').asc())
```

**Updated**: For older versions of Django, you have to rely on a pure Python implementation:

```
sorted(Model.objects.all(), key=lambda o: len(getattr(o, 'field')))
```